# What's the best way to separate each stone in an image with many stones (some above the others)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I need to make a study of the floor of a lake, and have to calculate the number and average size of the stones on the floor.

I have been studying morphological procedures to solve it in OpenCV but still need to find a way to try to separate the stones and make a binary image that precisely shows theirs contours.

I still didn't take the pictures, but the images will be something like the following:

[image]

What is the best algorithm to separate each stone and get their contours?
And if this kind of image is too complex to properly separate the stones, what is the best method to have a size x number estimation?

Comment: To find contours high pass filter can be used.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: This is a big research field. People do PhDs on designing algorithms for this. Do some research for existing methods

Comment: In essence what @AnderBiguri said -- I have a lot of experience with a similiar but definitively easier task and that is still effing hard (counting cells and subcellular structures in fluorescent images).

Answer (score 0):

Wathershed is probably what will give you an approximation to the solution.

Other thing that you may do is try labelling images with the number of flakes and particles you can count and feed it to a deep neural net and let it findout how to count the flakes, if you have enough training cases you may endup with a good result in the output

information on whatershed can be found at this link
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the "basic" contour detection based on Canny filter:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html
This simple method will not solve your problem, but no simple methods will. Still, you have to start with something to understand the complexity of your problem.